# PHP Como fazer uma imagem para ser o ícone padrão caso não tenha uma imagem selecionada?

Tags: php, imagem, upload

Quando uma pessoa seleciona uma imagem ela vai enviar a selecionada, mas se não selecionar escolha uma padrão. Como eu posso fazer isso?

Eu tava fazendo um código para o upload mais como eu posso adicionar essa funcionalidade?

```
$up = new Upload("file");
    if(!is_dir($path)):
            mkdir($path, 0755, true);
    endif;
    $up->setDir( $path )->setExtension( array( 'jpeg','jpg','png', 'gif' ) )->setSize( 2 );
    @$up->upload();

<?php

class Upload 
{    
    private $file = array();    
    public $dir;
    public $extension = array(); 
    public $size;
    public $name = array();

    public function __construct( $file )
    {
        $this->file = $_FILES[ $file ];        
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        $this->checkExtension()->size()->rename();

        if( is_array( $this->file[ "name" ] ) && !empty( $this->file[ "name" ] ) )
        {   
            foreach( $this->file[ "error" ] as $key => $error )
            {
                if( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK || !empty( $this->file[ "name" ][ $key ] ) )
                {
                    move_uploaded_file( $this->file[ "tmp_name" ][ $key ], $this->getDir() . $this->file[ "name" ][ $key ] );

                    $this->name[] = $this->file[ "name" ][ $key ];
                }
            }
        }
        elseif( !empty( $this->file[ "name" ] ) )
        {            
            move_uploaded_file( $this->file[ "tmp_name" ], $this->getDir() . $this->file[ "name" ] );
            $this->name[] = $this->file[ "name" ];
        }

        return $this->name;
    }

    public function checkExtension()
    {
        if( is_array( $this->extension ) )
        {
            $extensions = implode( "|", $this->extension );

            if( is_array( $this->file[ "name" ] ) )
            {
                foreach( $this->file[ "name" ] as $key => $val )
                {
                    if( !preg_match( "/.+\.({$extensions})/", $val ) )
                    {
                        $this->file[ "name" ][ $key ] = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if( !preg_match( "/.+\.({$extensions})/", $this->file[ "name" ] ) )
                {
                    unset( $this->file[ "name" ] );
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function size()
    {
        $size = $this->convertMbToBt();

        if( is_array( $this->file[ "size" ] ) )
        {
            foreach( $this->file[ "size" ] as $key => $sizes )
            {
                if( $sizes > $size )
                {
                    $this->file[ "name" ][ $key ] = "";
                    $this->file[ "size" ][ $key ] = "";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( $this->file[ "size" ] > $size )
            {
                unset( $this->file[ "size" ] );
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    private function convertMbToBt()
    {
        $size = $this->getSize() * ( 1024 * 1024 );
        return $size;
    }

    protected function rename()
    {
        if( is_array( $this->file[ "name" ] ) )
        {
            foreach( $this->file[ "name" ] as $key => $val )
            {
                if( !empty( $this->file[ "name" ][ $key ] ) )
                {
                    $exts = preg_split( "[\.]", $this->file[ "name" ][ $key ] );
                    $n = count( $exts ) - 1;            
                    $exts = $exts[ $n ];

                    $this->file[ "name" ] = time() . uniqid() . md5($this->file['name']) . "." . $exts;
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->file[ "name" ][ $key ] = "";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $exts = preg_split( "[\.]", $this->file[ "name" ] );
            $n = count( $exts ) - 1;            
            $exts = $exts[ $n ];
            $this->file[ "name" ] = time() . uniqid() . md5($this->file['name']) . "." . $exts;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDir()
    {
        return $this->dir;
    }

    public function setDir( $dir )
    {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getExtension()
    {
        return $this->extension;
    }

    public function setExtension( $extension )
    {
        $this->extension = $extension;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSize()
    {
        return $this->size;
    }

    public function setSize( $size ) 
    {
        $this->size = $size;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setName( $nomeFim ) 
    {
        $this->size = $size;
        return $this;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: você vai ler o nome do arquivo de imagem a partir de um banco de dados depois?

Comment: Isso, salvo numa pasta e o caminho no banco @Fbidu

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você poderia fazer uma verificação simples antes de chamar a classe de upload, algo do tipo:

```
if (isset($_FILES['arquivo']))
{
  "Executa ação de upload"
}
else
{ 
    "utiliza imagem padrão" caminho/imagem.jpg
}
```

Comment: Então eu queria ajuda pra selecionar a imagem, isso eu tinha feito mas precisava de algo para selecionar a imagem depois dessa verificação

Comment: Você quer fazer o upload de uma imagem padrão, é isso?

Comment: É isso ai que eu quero fazer, passar pela verificação (que nem essa ai emcima) e se tiver setado é o do $_FILES mesmo, mas se não tiver selecionar a imagem padrão. Eu não sei como selecionar a imagem padrão

Comment: Uma pergunta, por que refazer o upload de uma imagem(padrão) que já esta no diretório? não entendi.

Comment: É uma imagem para cada usuário. Eu quero copiar para pasta do próprio usuário

Comment: Você pode simplesmente fazer um link simbólico na pasta do usuário, ou manter todas as imagens num local. Não faz sentido você ter múltiplas cópias de uma imagem padrão

Comment: Isso que eu pensei, mesmo que for sortear entre várias imgs padrão o ideal por vários motivos seria, se não houver envio, simplesmente apontar uma imagem padrão que já esta lá.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma. Vamos usar como exemplo cadastro de usuário.

A cada novo usuário criado, você pode associar uma imagem `default.jpg` já localizada no seu projeto.

Para gerenciar você cria uma estrutura de banco de relacione a tabela de imagens com a do usuário. A tabela de imagens terá o nome da imagem e o caminho da imagem no projeto.

Quando o usuário fizer o *upload* da foto dele, salve a imagem no projeto e altere(`UPDATE`) no banco o caminho e o nome da imagem referente ao id do usuário, assim

```
UPDATE 
  `imagem` SET `nome`='perfil.jpg' AND caminho='caminho/salvo/no_projeto/imagem'
WHERE `id_usuario`= 3;
```

Referente ao processo de upload do arquivo com PHP

```
if (isset($_FILES) || isset($_POST['id'])) {
    throw new Exception('Erro ao carregar arquivo');
}

$file = $_FILES;
$user_id = $_POST['id'];

$config = [
    'type_file_allowed' => ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'],
    'size_allowed' => 1024 * 1024 * 5, // 5Mb
    'folder' => __DIR__ . 'tmp/', //caminho que irá salvar o arquivo,
    'format_name' => date('now'),
    'file_error_message' => [
        0 => 'Não houve erro e o upload foi bem sucedido.',
        1 => 'O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido.',
        2 => 'O arquivo excede o limite definido em MAX_FILE_SIZE no formulário HTML.',
        3 => 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente.',
        4 => 'Nenhum arquivo foi anexado',
        6 => 'Pasta temporária estar ausente.',
        7 => 'Falha ao escrever o arquivo em disco.',
        8 => 'Uma extensão do PHP interrompeu o upload do arquivo.'
    ]
];

//Pega extensão do arquivo
$extension = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!in_array($extension, $config['type_file_allowed'])) {
    throw new Exception('Extesão '. $extension .' do arquivo
    não permitida');
}

if($_FILES['size'] > $config['size_allowed']){
    throw new Exception('O arquivo enviado é muito grande, 
    envie arquivos de até 5Mb');
}

$file_name = $config['format_name'] . '.' . $extension;
$path = $config['folder'];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tmp_name'], $path . $file_name)) {
    $sql = printf("UPDATE `imagem` SET `nome`='%s' AND caminho='%s'
          WHERE `id_usuario`= '%s' ", $file_name, $path, $user_id);
    //$conn é conexão mysqli do banco
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Foto do perfil atualizado com sucesso";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: Não eu quero antes de inserir. Quero verificar no arquivo PHP e então mandar tudo certinho pro banco de dados

Comment: @Jow resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 0):

Eu preciso que quando ele, nesta etapa de cadastro de usuário, NÂO definir uma imagem, que entre uma padrão, alguma indicação? Obrigado